# to delete particular row from database as well as html table on corresponding button click

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, button

i want to delete particular row from my html as well as my database on corresponding button click in that row. so far i am able to delete it just from my html table but i don't know how to get it deleted from my database. I  know it will involve ajax code but i am not that familiar with using it so please help out
   here is my html-

```
<div id="divGrid">
                             <table class="footable" data-filter="#filter" id="tableresult">
                               <thead>

                                <th>Client name</th>
                                 <th>Staff name</th>
                                 <th>Matter</th>
                                 <th> Delete</th>
                              </thead>
                             <tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="edit_tr">

<td class="edit_td" >
<span id="client_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $clientname; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $clientname; ?>" class="editbox" id="client_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" /&gt;
</td>

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="staff_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $staff; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $staff; ?>" class="editbox" id="staff_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>

<td class="edit_td">
<span id="matter_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="text"><?php echo $matter; ?></span> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $matter; ?>" class="editbox" id="matter_input_<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</td>

<td class="delete_td"><input type="button" id="del"  class="btn btn-danger" value="&times;"></input></td>

</tr>
and here is my jquery-
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=button]').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        if ($('#tableresult tr').length < 2) {
            $('#divGrid').empty();
            $('#divGrid').html("All item removed");
        }

    });

});
```

so that i can implement my code on it. How do i do that?
please check out what is wrong with this-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=button]').click(function () {
       var row = $(this).attr('id');
       $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: 'delete.php',
             data: {id: row},
              success: function (result) {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        if ($('#tableresult tr').length < 2) {
            $('#divGrid').empty();
            $('#divGrid').html("All item removed");
        }
      }
    });
 });
});
```

php code-

Comment: What do you want to do? Your column has class `delete_td`. You can use this as the reference of column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your td has a class reference you can use that

```
$('.delete_td') <!--- references the entire td
```

You can also use the fact that the column is a parent to a button and retrieve all columns that hold buttons. But I think the code above answers the question

Comment: nope i want to delete particular row from database as well as html table on  corresponding button click in that row

Comment: actually i got that previous reference thing ..it was just a silly mistake but i dont know how do i delete the row from database so far i am just able to delete it from html table .am editing my code please help me with that

Comment: Your question asks to reference a column in an html table which the code does. Anyways you can use the id of the tr since I assume its the id of the record. You can then run sql that deletes that record in the database matching the id

Comment: i know but i am not that familiar with using ajax ..And i know this involves ajax.. so can u help out?

Comment: https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Ajax-Post-to-PHP-File-XMLHttpRequest-Object-Return-Data-Tutorial is a good start. And Ajax is one method but you can actually do it without ajax

Comment: how? i dont want the page to get redirected

Comment: Well Ajax would be the way to go. Have a look at that video and then you can ask any questions after that

Comment: This conversation is becoming very unrelated to the question. But I cant debug your code knowing what is being returned from your php script and knowing what you are having issues with outside of the php script.

I assumed an id of 12 and I used a dummy url to jus simulate what happens, a logical approach may look like this https://jsfiddle.net/4qd03oLw/